# Use of NATURAL JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql

According by the task I'm doing I need to change INNER JOIN to NATURAL JOIN and get the same result as this [result of inner join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXQvI.png)

I got that result with this query:

```
SELECT person_order.order_date,
    person.name || ' (' || 'age:' || person.age || ')' AS person_information
FROM person_order
    INNER JOIN person ON person_order.person_id = person.id
ORDER BY 1,
    2;
```

Here is what my tables look like [my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H87ut.png)

I'm trying to use subquery in a FROM statement but now result is differ with previous query [different rusult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6puXC.png)

```
SELECT pers_ord.order_date,
    person.name || ' (' || 'age:' || person.age || ')' AS person_information
FROM (
        SELECT order_date
        FROM person_order
    ) AS pers_ord
    NATURAL JOIN person
ORDER BY 1,
    2;
```

Comment: Avoid using natural joins like the plague. They are obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug. This is a section of SQL that IMHO should be deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try this:

```
SELECT pers_ord.order_date,
    person.name || ' (' || 'age:' || person.age || ')' AS person_information
FROM (
        SELECT order_date, person_id AS id
        FROM person_order
    ) AS pers_ord
    NATURAL JOIN person
ORDER BY 1,
    2;
```

Looking at examples [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-natural-join/) you can see the columns on which the join is performed need to be the same. And in your person_order table the person_id column is not matching the id in the person table.